# Jenkins Groovy List of Strings has doube Quotes in String value

Tags: jenkins, groovy, interpolation

Somewhat new to Groovy and Jenkins and wondering why some ArrayList of Strings print and seem to have a value with double quotes and other ArrayList of Strings have no double quotes and do not print with double quotes.

example curl response in Jenkins from artifactory where uri values are placed into Array:

```
response = {"repo" : "helm-repo",
  "path" : "/helm-chart/helpdesk/core",
  "created" : "2023-05-12T16:04:55.905-04:00",
  "createdBy" : "coolUser",
  "lastModified" : "2023-05-12T16:04:55.905-04:00",
  "modifiedBy" : "coolUser",
  "lastUpdated" : "2023-05-12T16:04:55.905-04:00",
  "children" : [ {
    "uri" : "/core-1.0.10.tgz",
    "folder" : false
  }, {
    "uri" : "/core-1.0.18.tgz",
    "folder" : false
  }, ]
}

def versions = []
response.get("children", []).each
                { item ->
                    if (item?."folder" == false) {
                        versions.add(item.uri)
                    }
                }
logInfo(versions)
>>> Output: [core-1.0.18.tgz, core-1.0.10.tgz]
```

But other Lists have double quotes, like when I use the az cli to grab tags in a repo and turn the string result into a list:

```
def tagList = sh(
            script: "az acr repository show-tags -n acrHub --repository ${repo} -u userName -p passwordCred",
            returnStdout: true
    )
// tagList is a String, formatted like an array with each item in double quotes
// Like [
//        "1.1.1",
//        "1.3.3"
//      ]

tagList = tagList.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").split(',') as List
// when converting to List using as List, I get extra brackets, so I removed them, put them on the same line and split them on the comma

logInfo(tagList)
>>> Output: ["core-1.0.18.tgz", "core-1.0.10.tgz"]
```

I am struggling to understand the behavior and difference here. It comes into play if I try and interpolate the values from the `tagList` that have quotes, into another string

```
logInfo("/buildPath/with/item/${versions[0]}")
>>> Output: /buildPath/with/item/core-1.0.18.tgz

logInfo("/buildPath/with/item/${tagList[0]}")
>>> Output: /buildPath/with/item/"core-1.0.18.tgz"
```

Any insight on what I don't know and am missing here?

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide an examples of both cases. You vaguely describe what is going on, but neither of your code samples helps to reproduce the problem. The first example can not be compiled, the second contains `sh` script with unknown output. Could you please update your question and provide 2 code snippets that everyone can run locally and see the problem?